# MySQL rows to columns dynamically

Tags: mysql, pivot, transpose, group-concat

I'm trying to construct a mySQL query that get rows to columns, I achieved a closest result but it's not what I need yet and I already spent a lot of time on it and could not figure out what I'm missing.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SET @sql = NULL;

SET @rank=0;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
     CONCAT(
        'MAX(CASE WHEN cpus.hardware_id= ''',
         cpus.hardware_id,
         ''' THEN cpus.type END) AS CPU',@rank:=@rank+1
           )
     )INTO @sql
 FROM  
     hardware
 LEFT JOIN  cpus ON hardware.id = cpus.hardware_id;


 SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT hardware.id, ',@sql,' FROM   
     hardware
     JOIN cpus ON hardware.id = cpus.hardware_id GROUP BY hardware.id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The result of this query is:

```
|id|CPU1                                     |CPU2                                 |CPU3                                |
|10|Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2407 0 @ 2.20GHz |NULL                                 |NULL                                | 
|11|NULL                                     |Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5530 @ 2.40GHz |Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5530 @ 2.40GHz|
```

And the result that I need to achieve is:

```
|id|CPU1                                     |CPU2                                 |
|10|Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2407 0 @ 2.20GHz |NULL                                 |
|11|Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5530 @ 2.40GHz     |Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5530 @ 2.40GHz |
```

The query needs to be dynamic because I can have multiple CPUs for each hardware.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a621c/1)

Any help on this is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you even need dynamic SQL.  If you want two columns, you can do:

```
select cpus.hardware_id as id, min(cpus.type) as cpu1,
       (case when min(cpus.type) <> max(cpus.type) then max(cpus.type) end) as cpu2
from cpus
group by cpus.hardware_id;
```

Comment: I need dynamic because I can have many rows as CPU, it depends of each hardware device. For this sample data the maximum CPU are 2, but if I have another hardware with more CPUs, the query should return all of them.

Answer (score 0):

How i hate those pivot query questions. I really do believe you don't gain any advantage whatsoever in trying to solve this in sql. I mean, sql is a language for really structured data. Especially, if you only want an id and multiple CPU fields:

why not fetch

```
id | number | CPU
---+--------+-----------------------------
 1 |      1 | first cpu description
 1 |      2 | second cpu description
 1 |    ... | ...
 2 |      1 | ...
```

I mean, whatever code you have on the software side will probably cycle through these cpus anyway, I suspect. Now on the software side you just collect the cpus as long as the id is the same.

Alternatively you could in mysql just group_concat with some separator that doesn't appear in the cpu field or use one of those new json functions. (Yes, I used to obsess over those queries as well. And simpler is almost always better.)